# Why do we need express in the frontend?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I am quite new to javascript and web application environment. I have seen an express web application project which had a public directory, a client directory, and a server directory. I have a questions

- Why do we need an express server file setup in the frontend project
  if we already have backend APIs ready and backend server ready

**Any suggestion, please**
(I have read some article from google, but I need your opinion)
Thanks.

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the specific project. It may be a developent tool, or cruft left from a previous version of the project. The app may expect to have a separate server handle routing and static files and allow the api to specialize in being an api. This is all speculation, of course.

Comment: Actually, we can fetch backend api data without any express server it is normal rules, but i have seen some of udemy tutorials with the biggest project they are using express server both side in frontend and backend, here is my confusion. 

Is it better way or not!

Answer (score 3):

This is a matter of choice.

1. Backend + frontend

- You can use express as your backend server that exposes Rest API's to be consumed by the frontend.
- You are then free to choose whatever frontend framework you like. The usual ones are vue, react or angular.

2. Server side rendering

- You can use still use express as the backend and use it to render pages for the frontend (pages defined in the public directory)

*Here's my two cents:*

- If I have the time on a project or if I work with different developers, I would go with separated Backend + Frontend. It is easier to maintain. You don't want frontend guys touching backend code and vice-versa. The separation is clear, we can also freely change the framework we use on the frontend/backend since we have a contract that we follow aka API's.
- If the project needs to be done quickly and most of the pages are simple (don't need to maintain too much state, etc.), I would go with option 2.

It's really up to you and your team to decide.

Comment: Thank's for your opinion